# INSERT query shows data inserted but actually no data is inserted

Tags: c#, sql-server, query-string

I run a parameterized `INSERT` query, it returns 1 (1 row is inserted). But when I view the table in SSMSE, I see nothing. The return statement in the code below returns 1.

Here is the code:

```
SqlCommand insertProject=new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_project (id, project_name, project_desc, creator_user_id) VALUES('@id', '@project_name', '@project_desc', @creator_user_id)", conn);
insertProject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
insertProject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_name", project_name);
insertProject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@project_desc", project_desc);
insertProject.Parameters.AddWithValue("@creator_user_id", creator_user_id);

return insertProject.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: place holders should not be quoted. e.g. `VALUES(@id, @project_name, etc...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parameter name should never be enclose with single quote.

```
SqlCommand insertProject = new SqlCommand("Insert into tbl_project 
                (id,project_name,project_desc,creator_user_id) 
          VALUES(@id,@project_name,@project_desc,@creator_user_id)",conn);
```